# Which NVIDIA driver am I supposed to switch to?

Tags: graphic-drivers, nvidia

Am I supposed to switch to nvidia-346 or nvidia-346-updates?

The Additional Drivers application tells me that nvidia-346 has been tested, but some people tell me to use the updates one. Which one should I switch to?

I am currently using the Nouveau display driver.

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu version of driver has some problem with Wine, so I recommend you to install the driver from this page: [https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Egraphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)

command:

> sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
>
> sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get install nvidia-355

They don't recommend people to install the latest nvidia-358, they say that it is buggy.

Answer (score -1):

Use the lastest 352.55 from [home page](http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html)
If u get the black screen. Just use the trick `nomodeset` [here](https://elementaryforums.com/index.php?threads/howto-install-latest-nvidia-driver-on-linux-without-getting-black-screen.7/)
I'm using freya and 352.55 driver now

Comment: This might not work for everyone. Older GPU's might not be supported in the 35* driver series.

Comment: if you have Nvidia graphic card,you can install driver from the homepage.